# Segue to next MVC -> Cells detail view in swift

Tags: swift, ios8, xcode6

I am working on an app that uses a splitviewcontroller. On the left (masterviewcontroller) there is a table with a schedule of items that will be worked on in the detail view controller.

In the detail view controller (on the right) after a user is done with an item and is ready to move onto the next I have a button that submits their answers to a server.

How to I make it so that when I confirm the submission was successful it automatically segues to the next item (cell) in the list?

I know that I can do: `self.performSegueWithIdentifier("showDetail", sender: self)` to initiate a segue, i'm just unsure how to get the next items cell index information to pass to my prepare for segue function so that the correct data appears in the detail view controller...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no built-in method to increment the indexPath.

You'll have to determine if there are more rows in the section (by comparing your current row against `numberOfRowsInSection`).

If there are more rows, create a new indexPath for the next row.  If not, and there are more sections, create an indexPath for the first row of the next section.  Otherwise, you're at the end.

Then fetch the data for that following cell, and pass it to the detailViewController in the "showDetail" `performForSegue`.